# Asterisk RTP re-invite not working

Tags: asterisk

I’m experiencing the following scenario in Asterisk, and was wondering if you could help:

1. Asterisk source IP sends call to destination signalling IP
2. Destination signalling IP answers call, specifying destination media IP
3. Destination signalling IP then later sends re-invite to Asterisk source IP asking to change destination media IP
4. Asterisk source IP accepts re-invite with `200 OK`, but for some reason keeps sending RTP to original destination media IP

So basically the issue is that Asterisk doesn’t seem to be changing the media IP it sends the RTP to, in spite of the fact it’s accepting the request at the SIP level. I’ve included a suitably redacted SIP trace of an example call at the bottom to illustrate. I’m using `chan_sip` in Asterisk 13.23.1. I’ve looked at the `directmedia` setting in `sip.conf`, but it doesn’t seem to be relevant as this is about changing the destination media IP. I've also tried the various `strictrtp` settings in `rtp.conf`, but none of them fix the issue.

Here are the contents of `sip.conf`:

```
[general]
language=en
useragent=iConsole
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=5060
port=5060
context=from-sip
directmedia=no
nat=force_rport,comedia
dtmfmode=rfc2833
rtptimeout=300
rtpholdtimeout=300
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
allowoverlap=no
srvlookup=yes
ignoresdpversion=yes
t38pt_udptl=yes
session-timers=originate
insecure=port,invite
```

And here's the example SIP trace:

```
U 2019/04/18 10:32:20.129798 [Source signalling IP]:5060 -> [Destination signalling IP]:5060
INVITE sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP] SIP/2.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5b1be354;rport.
Max-Forwards: 70.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>.
Contact: <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]:5060>.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 102 INVITE.
User-Agent: iConsole.
Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2019 09:32:20 GMT.
Session-Expires: 1800.
Min-SE: 90.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE.
Supported: replaces, timer.
P-Asserted-Identity: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>.
Content-Type: application/sdp.
Content-Length: 299.
.
v=0.
o=root 2043154992 2043154992 IN IP4 [Source media IP].
s=Asterisk PBX 13.23.1.
c=IN IP4 [Source media IP].
t=0 0.
m=audio 41738 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 101.
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000.
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000.
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000.
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000.
a=fmtp:101 0-16.
a=ptime:20.
a=maxptime:150.
a=sendrecv.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:20.167590 [Destination signalling IP]:5060 -> [Source signalling IP]:5060
SIP/2.0 100 Trying.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5b1be354;rport.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 102 INVITE.
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:20.221067 [Destination signalling IP]:5060 -> [Source signalling IP]:5060
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5b1be354;rport.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 102 INVITE.
Contact: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]:5060>.
Content-Length: 0.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, NOTIFY, REFER, PRACK, INFO, UPDATE, MESSAGE.
Record-Route: <sip:[Destination signalling IP]:5060;lr>.
Supported: replaces, 100rel.
.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:20.225010 [Destination signalling IP]:5060 -> [Source signalling IP]:5060
SIP/2.0 200 Ok.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5b1be354;rport.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 102 INVITE.
Contact: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]:5060>.
Content-Type: application/sdp.
Content-Length: 259.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, NOTIFY, REFER, PRACK, INFO, UPDATE, MESSAGE.
Record-Route: <sip:[Destination signalling IP]:5060;lr>.
Supported: replaces, 100rel.
.
v=0.
o=aculab-00ACF801 30597 30597 IN IP4 [Initial destination media IP].
s=-.
c=IN IP4 [Initial destination media IP].
t=0 0.
m=audio 21082 RTP/AVP 8 101.
c=IN IP4 [Initial destination media IP].
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000.
a=ptime:20.
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000.
a=fmtp:101 0-15.
a=ptime:20.
a=ptime:20.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:20.225181 [Source signalling IP]:5060 -> [Destination signalling IP]:5060
ACK sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]:5060 SIP/2.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK22c119c0;rport.
Route: <sip:[Destination signalling IP]:5060;lr>.
Max-Forwards: 70.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
Contact: <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]:5060>.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 102 ACK.
User-Agent: iConsole.
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:40.612245 [Destination signalling IP]:5060 -> [Source signalling IP]:5060
INVITE sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]:5060 SIP/2.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Destination signalling IP];rport;branch=z9hG4bK1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765.
Max-Forwards: 70.
From: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
To: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 103 INVITE.
Contact: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]:5060>.
Content-Type: application/sdp.
Content-Length: 211.
Supported: replaces, 100rel.
.
v=0.
o=C3PCALL0 1555579960 1555579960 IN IP4 [New destination media IP].
s=-.
c=IN IP4 [New destination media IP].
t=0 0.
m=audio 20020 RTP/AVP 8 101.
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000.
a=ptime:20.
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000.
a=fmtp:101 0-15.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:40.612444 [Source signalling IP]:5060 -> [Destination signalling IP]:5060
SIP/2.0 100 Trying.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Destination signalling IP];branch=z9hG4bK1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765;received=[Destination signalling IP];rport=5060.
From: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
To: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 103 INVITE.
Server: iConsole.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE.
Supported: replaces, timer.
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uas.
Contact: <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]:5060>.
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:40.612496 [Source signalling IP]:5060 -> [Destination signalling IP]:5060
SIP/2.0 200 OK.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Destination signalling IP];branch=z9hG4bK1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765;received=[Destination signalling IP];rport=5060.
From: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
To: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 103 INVITE.
Server: iConsole.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE.
Supported: replaces, timer.
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uas.
Contact: <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]:5060>.
Content-Type: application/sdp.
Content-Length: 299.
.
v=0.
o=root 2043154992 2043154993 IN IP4 [Source media IP].
s=Asterisk PBX 13.23.1.
c=IN IP4 [Source media IP].
t=0 0.
m=audio 41738 RTP/AVP 8 0 3 101.
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000.
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000.
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000.
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000.
a=fmtp:101 0-16.
a=ptime:20.
a=maxptime:150.
a=sendrecv.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:40.623395 [Destination signalling IP]:5060 -> [Source signalling IP]:5060
ACK sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]:5060 SIP/2.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Destination signalling IP];rport;branch=z9hG4bK1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765.
Max-Forwards: 70.
From: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
To: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 103 ACK.
Contact: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]:5060>.
Content-Length: 0.
Supported: replaces, 100rel.
.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:52.168069 [Source signalling IP]:5060 -> [Destination signalling IP]:5060
BYE sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]:5060 SIP/2.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK589b107e;rport.
Route: <sip:[Destination signalling IP]:5060;lr>.
Max-Forwards: 70.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 103 BYE.
User-Agent: iConsole.
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing.
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16.
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 2019/04/18 10:32:52.182326 [Destination signalling IP]:5060 -> [Source signalling IP]:5060
SIP/2.0 200 Ok.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [Source signalling IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK589b107e;rport.
From: "[Source number]" <sip:[Source number]@[Source signalling IP]>;tag=as52fa238f.
To: <sip:[Destination number]@[Destination signalling IP]>;tag=1b10d58e81c1742e.
Call-ID: 1a78edfd6fbc9c8b659a4ef56fe54765@[Source signalling IP]:5060.
CSeq: 103 BYE.
Content-Length: 0.
.
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do

```
directmedia=yes
directrtpsetup=yes
canreinvite=yes
```

Or ask your provider not do reinvites.

Comment: Yeah I've tried the different `directmedia` and `directrtpsetup` settings to no avail, and I believe `canreinvite` is just the old name for `directmedia` (according to [this](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-sip-canreinvite/) it was renamed in Asterisk 1.6.2).

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs because when the asterisk receives a reINVITE the SDP version remains the same as in the first INVITE (v = 0), so Asterisk identifies that it does not hear the SDP change, and does not apply the new parameters.
For Asterisk to fully reapply all SDP parameters for each INVITE triggered in the session, it will depend on the parameter in your SIP trunk settings:

ignoresdpversion=yes

This should probably solve your problem.